# Help with a Playstation2 dance pad to usb adapter

Tags: dance-dance-revolution, stepmania

I'm trying to play DDR on my computer by using Stepmania and I have an old Red Octane metal dance pad, but the adapter to change VGA to PS2 is missing. I've been looking for an adapter on Amazon to turn VGA to USB, but can't seem to find that directly, only USB to VGA. Basically, here is my question:

- Does the "to" format of the adapter really matter? Will a USB to VGA cord solve my problem? (It also looks like the stock cord is female VGA, so I think I may need to do male to male VGA, then USB to female VGA) or will that not work and I need to find another solution?
- I just wanted to verify that this is VGA input:
  [image]

If anyone else has a solution on how to get this input to a USB output and if that will work as easily for my computer as I'm hoping, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

That's a DE-15 connector, the same kind as used with VGA cables, but it's not a VGA connector. VGA cables only carry analogue video, they're not used to connect any sort of controller. Your dance pad has a proprietary connector that happens to have same shape as VGA connector, but serves a much difference purpose and isn't compatible. Any VGA to USB adapter you might find would essentially be a capture card. Connecting your dance pad to such a device would be as useful as connecting your pad to a computer monitor or video card.

Unfortunately this means in order to connect this to your PC you'll probably need find the original adapter. Since it's a proprietary interface for an obscure and obsolete game controller finding a third party replacement isn't going to be easy. I found these two control boxes that might work as they both use 15-pin connectors, but neither lists any model of Red Octane pad as being compatible:

- [Dance Dance Revolution Control Box for PS/PS2 Metal Dance Pads (15-pin male)](http://www.ddrgame.com/dance-dance-revolution-control-box-ps2.html)
- [Dance Dance Revolution 4-in-1 Control Box for PS2 / Xbox / PC/ Wii with Blue Buttons (15-pin male)](http://www.ddrgame.com/dance-dance-revolution-control-box-4-in-1-blue.html)

You'll may also need to get a PlayStation controller to USB adapter, but these shouldn't be too hard to find. However, don't confuse a PlayStation 2 controller to USB adapter with a PS/2 to USB adapter. The former device is for connecting controllers that use [Sony's proprietary interface](http://connector.pinouts.ru/9_pin_Sony_Playstation_special/) to a PC, while the second device is for connecting keyboards and mice that use the [legacy PS/2 interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port).